# iOS portrait videos rotated 90 degrees CCW with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, video, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

In my iOS app, I load videos from a URL and play them in my controller:

```
  self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
  [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];
  [self.player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height - 44)];
  [self.player play];

  [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
```

This works fine for video shot in landscape, but videos that were shot in portrait are always rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise.

**How do I check the orientation of the video and ensure it's played in the correct orientation?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could get the width and height of the video itself with [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/naturalSize) property to know if its landscape or portrait.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)determineOrentationVideoWhenVideoWasRecorded:(AVAsset *)asset {

```
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
CGSize size = [videoTrack naturalSize];
CGAffineTransform txf = [videoTrack preferredTransform];

if (size.width == txf.tx && size.height == txf.ty)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == 0)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == size.width)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```